# Connecting to a remote linux machine from windows using SSH give permission denied error

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

So I am here new to ssh. I tried making a localhost connection on my Windows 10 device and it worked but I want to connect to a remote Linux machine.For this I am executing a statement for ssh on the cmd but it always gives me permission denied error while connecting to it. It asks for the password and then gives this error. Can anyone tell me how to configure it?

This is what I get as error when I run it in command prompt.

```
D:\Internship\Temporary Files>ssh connect@192.168.137.248
connect@192.168.137.248's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: First, confirm the password is indeed correct. Second, make sure password authentication is enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` .

Comment: Is "connect" a valid user id on the linux system? Also, i assume you are entering the correct password for the user "connect". Are you able to login to the linux system directly (e.g. on the console) with the user "connect"? Have you tried using putty? If so, What credentials did you use in putty? Did it work when using putty?

Comment: @AmirAsyraf yes I am giving the correct password and also password authentication is set to yes. Is is that I have to be on same network because it also says "Permission denied (publickey,password)". What if both device are on different networks.

Comment: @GMc yes, using putty I got connected to the Linux machine. Actually I am connecting it to a raspberry pi. I used the same name "pi" and the password and it worked. Am I doing something wrong with the syntax of ssh on cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the format of the ssh command (or at least the bits you need) is:

```sh
ssh remoteuser@host
```

since you are logging in to Raspberry Pi and you indicated putty worked with the user `pi`, the correct command would be:

```sh
ssh pi@192.168.137.248
```

I assume that 192.168.137.248 is the IP address of the Raspberry Pi (If not, make sure you use the IP of the rasbperry pi).

With regard to your "on the same network" question, if you were not on the same network (or there was no route to the network with the Pi), then you would not have seen the "Pasword:" prompt. Instead you would have got a timeout or "no route to host" error. If it were a firewall issue, you would have got a timeout or a "connection refused" error.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. It is working now. Also can you clarify one more thing that does both device need to be on same network. What if not?

Comment: can you accept my answer pls? In relation to the "one more thing to clarify", that is basically a how does the internet, or more generally, how does networking work? That is a whole 'nother question. But basically the box that your home LAN plugs into (you might call it a modem - terminology varies) provides many functions to get you "onto the net". One of those functions is routing. Which basically means, if you can not find the IP address in your home LAN, where should you try next. Routing deals with the "What if not?" part of your followup, but again, it is a major topic all by itself.